# Apache FOP: Embedded Font detected but not renderered properly?

Tags: apache-fop

[Incorrect Text](https://i.stack.imgur.com/83Ywr.png)

Having config file that's being read with embedded font:

```
    <font embed-url="FuturaPTBook.ttf" embedding-mode="subset">
        <font-triplet name="Futura PT Book" style="normal" weight="400"/>
           <font-triplet name="any" style="normal" weight="normal"/>
    </font>
```

Without the above declaration I get below error

WARNING: Font "Futura PT Book,normal,400" not found. Substituting with "any,normal,400".

When I add the declaration - the error goes away but the resulting font doesnt seem to be correct even though it finds it

The top "Futura" is the right font - the bottom "Futura" is from the generated pdf and is showing up as Calibri.

Does anyone know why FOP is not rendering the Futura font even though it is able to find it?

I have the font-family="Futura PT Book" in the XSL code. I am passing in config file command line
fop.bat -c fop.xconf -xml Test.xml -xsl tmp.xsl -foout tmp.fo

Confused why it seems to find the Futura font but ends up using a different font when producing a PDF.

Comment: Thanks for input - removed that line but still seeing same results Calibri vs Expected Futura